# Как показать уведомление в X11 на Linux поверх экрана входа/блокировки?

Tags: linux, desktop, x11

Подумываю запилить приложение-демон (для десктопа), и по сути своей оно должно как-то периодически уведомлять о своей работе на экране. При этом демон этот не зависит от текущего пользователя, и он должен иметь возможность отправлять уведомления всегда, когда запущены иксы:

- когда какой-нибудь пользователь таки сидит работает за компом;
- когда он ушёл, заблокировав экран;
- когда компьютер только-только включили и ещё отображается окно входа в систему;
- желательно, но не обязательно: когда отображается какой-нибудь скринсейвер.

Я хочу отображать уведомления поверх всего этого. Есть ли такая возможность?

Конкретные инструменты и внешний вид мне не принципиальны, можно хоть notify-send/xmessage (если возможно их так настроить), хоть скрипт на питоне с каким-нибудь pygtk, хоть прямое подключение к иксам на сишечке, дальше я сам разберусь.

Comment: OSD если мне не изменяет память позволяет отправлять сообщения на дисплей даже поверх блокировщика, поиграйтесь вначале с pyosd.

Comment: @0andriy неа, поверх блокировщика не показывает

Comment: OK, исправили значит, потому как лет 5 назад эта ошибка проявлялась.

Answer (score 0):

- *когда какой-нибудь пользователь таки сидит работает за компом;* - notify-send или программа, которая работает от имени пользователя, добавлена в "автозагрузку"
- *желательно, но не обязательно: когда отображается какой-нибудь скринсейвер.* - свой скринсейвер. Хотя notify-send иногда умеет пробиваться.
- *когда компьютер только-только включили и ещё отображается окно входа в систему;* - смотреть в апи каждого "менеджера входа" или написать свой.
- *когда он ушёл, заблокировав экран;* - тут запускается либо локер (тогда это 3 пункт) либо скринсейвер - это второй пункт. Либо гасится монитор, вплоть до ухода в спящий режим - тут только ментальный канал.

А в целом, очень похоже на попытку написать winlocker, только под линукс.